# Terraform - using rds snapshot when available

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, snapshot

I try to find a solution for this problem.

When a rds instance is created with terraform it should use the most recent snapshot available. But when there is no snapshot available the rds instance should created without a snapshot.

I tried to use a data element but the apply always states:

> Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.

How can I achieve this? To give some more context. I would like to create a fresh environment with terraform or ensure that the rds instance is recreated with the latest snapshot with the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to pass a variable into your Terraform indicating if it is a "fresh environment" or "environment with snapshot". You could give a default value to that variable so you don't need to pass it all the time.

For example if you are normally running this Terraform with an existing environment, you could have a `fresh_environment` variable with a default value of `false`. Then only when you are running it to create a brand new environment would you need to pass `-var fresh_environment=true` in your terraform command.